# Ubuntu 22.04 wakes from suspend immediately

Tags: 22.04, suspend, wakeup

I have installed Ubuntu about a month ago and ever since then I have had an issue where my PC immediately wakes itself up from a suspended state.
While I have found some band-aid fixes, my ideal solution would be, that I am able to wake my PC by pressing a key on my keyboard.

The partial solution I have found, involves disabling certain devices in the `/proc/acpi/wakeup` directory. Running `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` gave the following output:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GP12      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
GP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:08:00.3
GP30      S4    *disabled
GP31      S4    *disabled
PS2K      S3    *disabled
GPP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.1
GPP8      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.1
PTXH      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0
PT20      S4    *disabled
PT21      S4    *disabled
PT22      S4    *disabled
PT23      S4    *disabled
PT24      S4    *disabled
PT26      S4    *disabled
PT27      S4    *disabled
PT28      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:08.0
PT29      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:09.0
```

After some trial and error, I was able to determine that disabling the wakeup abilities for devices `GPP0` and `PTXH` caused the system to stay in the suspend state. This however does not allow my keyboard to wake my PC.

Here are some more logs, to make troubleshooting easier:

`lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 08bb:2902 Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c545 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e8d:0608 MediaTek Inc. Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 534d:2109 MacroSilicon MiraBox Capture
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`journalctl`

```
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.3506] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver ModemManager[828]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.3508] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver google-chrome.desktop[3425]: [3417:3451:1216/105054.353359:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(471)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver wpa_supplicant[786]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4084] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4085] device (eno1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver dbus-daemon[746]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=747 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver dbus-daemon[746]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4437] device (eno1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:810d:ae3f:e118:cdbb:1db2:a54:48d on eno1.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:810d:ae3f:e118:b74d:d302:7a7f:c2d5 on eno1.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address 2a02:810d:ae3f:e118:b74d:d302:7a7f:c2d5.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4442] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Registering new address record for fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671 on eno1.*.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4442] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671 on eno1.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4442] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed no lease
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address fe80::6395:16a6:7123:8671.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4443] dhcp6 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Interface eno1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4443] dhcp6 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4443] dhcp6 (eno1): state changed no lease
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.55 on eno1.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.55.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-resolved[663]: eno1: Bus client reset search domain list.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver avahi-daemon[741]: Interface eno1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-resolved[663]: eno1: Bus client set default route setting: no
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-resolved[663]: eno1: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver wpa_supplicant[786]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver wpa_supplicant[786]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver NetworkManager[747]: <info>  [1702720254.4875] device (eno1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  457.240453] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 11 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Successfully made thread 5486 of process 1747 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Dec 16 10:50:54 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 12 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:55 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 11 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:55 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Successfully made thread 5501 of process 1747 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Dec 16 10:50:55 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 12 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver logger[5505]: <13>Dec 16 10:50:56 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 11 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Successfully made thread 5521 of process 1747 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 12 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 11 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Successfully made thread 5523 of process 1747 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 12 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "40"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "43"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event3  - Logitech USB Receiver: device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event10 - UVC Camera (046d:0825): device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event2  - Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC : device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Receiver Keyboard: device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event5  - Logitech G Pro : device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (**) Option "fd" "81"
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) event18 - WH-1000XM4 (AVRCP): device removed
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 11 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Successfully made thread 5524 of process 1747 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver rtkit-daemon[1311]: Supervising 12 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:74
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:82
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.659485] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 68
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.659712] rfkill: input handler enabled
Dec 16 10:50:56 Ubuntu-Oliver acpid: client 1901[1000:1000] has disconnected
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver systemd-sleep[5525]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.893516] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver bluetoothd[742]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 23
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver gsd-media-keys[2158]: Unable to get default sink
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) config/udev: removing device WH-1000XM4 (AVRCP)
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.895589] Filesystems sync: 0.002 seconds
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Dec 16 10:50:57 Ubuntu-Oliver /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1901]: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to release device: Device not taken
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.900481] Freezing user space processes
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.902174] Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.902176] OOM killer disabled.
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.902177] Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.903310] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.903327] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.939560] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.939563] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.939668] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  459.943992] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  460.552855] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.324102] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.324189] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.326551] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.329287] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.331943] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.334485] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.336988] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.339366] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.341579] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.343742] smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.344278] Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP off
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.345799] smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.347904] smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.349880] smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.352227] smpboot: CPU 12 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.354101] smpboot: CPU 13 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.356882] smpboot: CPU 14 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.358715] smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.359448] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.359466] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.359618] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.360100] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.360141] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.360141] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.368372] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.368933] CPU1 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.368952] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.371240] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C004: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.372570] CPU2 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.372602] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.374887] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C006: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.376400] CPU3 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.376419] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.378705] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C008: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.380427] CPU4 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.380444] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.382734] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00A: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.384457] CPU5 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.384479] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0xc
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.386769] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00C: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.388499] CPU6 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.388523] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0xe
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.390814] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00E: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.392541] CPU7 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.392563] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x1
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.394900] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C001: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.396731] Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.396735] CPU8 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.396755] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x3
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.399060] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C003: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.400654] CPU9 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.400679] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x5
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.403019] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.404747] CPU10 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.404782] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0x7
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.407088] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C007: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.408818] CPU11 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.408839] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0x9
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.411149] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C009: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.412883] CPU12 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.412903] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0xb
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.415214] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00B: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.416962] CPU13 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.416985] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0xd
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.419300] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00D: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.421037] CPU14 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.421057] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0xf
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.423373] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00F: Found 2 idle states
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.425121] CPU15 is up
Dec 16 10:51:05 Ubuntu-Oliver kernel: [  461.426754] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
```